# php mb_strlen return value is weird

Tags: php, strlen

gb2312 is a double byte character set, using mb_strlen() to check a single chinese character will return 2, but for 2 more characters,sometimes the result is weird,  anybody know why? how can I get the right length?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');//
$a="大";
echo mb_strlen($a,'gb2312'); // output 2
echo mb_strlen($a.$a,'gb2312'); // output 3 , it should be 4
echo mb_strlen($a.'a','gb2312'); // output 2, it should be 3
echo mb_strlen('a'.$a,'gb2312'); // output 3, 
?>
```

thanks deceze, your document is very helpful, people know little about encoding like me should read it.[What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: What is the encoding of the file you have `$a="大";` in?

Comment: If you say the string is encoded in gb2312 then it actually needs to be encoded in gb2312... This should be of interest: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: thanks, i have already tried gb2312, euc-cn,hz, utf-8, latin1 before I came here asking for help.

Comment: @user995789: Your comment *"utf-8,latin1,whatever"* is exactly the cause of your problem. You can continue to guess and try widely or (alternatively) try learn more and understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is probably stored as UTF-8.

The UTF-8 code for `"大"` is `E5 A4 A7` (according to [this webpage](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)), so:

```
$a       // 3 bytes, gb2312 -> 2 char (1 + 0.5)
$a . $a  // 6 bytes, gb2312 -> 3 char
$a . 'a' // 4 bytes, gb2312 -> 2 char
'a' . $a // 4 bytes, first byte is <128 so will be interpreted as one
         // single character, gb2312 -> 3 char
```

This is just a guess, but perfectly make sense to me if thinking this way. You can probably refer to [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312#EUC-CN).

If you really want to test, I recommend you to create a separated file saved in gb2312 encoding, and use `fopen` or whatever to read it. Then you will be sure that it is in the desired encoding.

Comment: thanks, I think it is because of the encoding of Euc_cn [php supported encodings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), if use "HZ", mb_strlen() works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the MB internal encoding to UTF-8

```
/* Set internal character encoding to UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: I was assuming your input to be UTF-8, but it sounds like it must not be. Regardless, it sounds like mb_* is not using the correct encoding for your input.

Comment: Sorry, I see now you were specifying the encoding, which would override what I suggested anyway.

Comment: This worked for me, I was trying to get the physical amount of characters like `mb_strlen("æ") == 1` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use utf-8 instead gb2312

try this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');//
$a="大";
echo mb_strlen($a,'utf8'); // output 1
echo mb_strlen($a.$a,'utf8'); // output 2 
echo mb_strlen($a.'a','utf8'); // output 2
echo mb_strlen('a'.$a,'utf8'); // output 2, 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing `$a = "大";` into a PHP file, the variable `$a` contains a byte sequence of whatever was between the quotes in your source code file. If that source code file was saved in UTF-8, the string is a UTF-8 byte sequence representing the character "大". If the source code file was saved in GB2312, it is the GB2312 byte sequence representing "大". But a PHP file saved in GB2312 won't actually parse as valid PHP, since PHP needs an ASCII compatible encoding.

`mb_strlen` is supposed to give you the number of *characters* in the given string in the specified encoding. I.e. `mb_strlen('大', 'gb2312')` expects the string to be a GB2312 byte sequence representation and is supposed to return ***1***. You're wrong in expecting it to return 2, even if GB2312 is a double byte encoding. `mb_strlen` returns the number of *characters*.

`strlen('大')` would give you the number the *bytes*, because it's a naïve old-style functions which doesn't know anything about encodings and only counts bytes.

The bottom-line being: your expectation was wrong, and you have a mismatch between what the "大" is actually encoded in (whatever you saved your source code as) and what you tell `mb_strlen` it is encoded in (`gb2312`). Therefore `mb_strlen` cannot do its job correctly and gives you varying random results.

Comment: thank you, very detailed explanation, I think the preset encoding(through mb_internal_encoding() or header or <meta>) only works when the 2nd argument is omitted in mb_str(string,encoding). if you set the argument, mb_strlen() will encode the string then calculate its length. I think my problem is because of the GB2312 encoding,maybe gb2312 or EUC-CN is not a good choice for this function, 'HZ' is more stable, there is another GB18030,but it is for Php5.4+, I have not check it.

Comment: You need to use the encoding that the string is actually in, not what you want it to be in!

Comment: hi,after reading your document, I found I am deeply wrong, thank you.